# There isn't any error in my code but it doesn't run. I guess problem about "stack"

Tags: c++, stack

I can't find out any error from my code, but it doesn't run.
I have tried hard to find it out but I couldn't find out why don't it run.
I just learned how to use 'stack' so maybe there is something wrong in my code.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
int main()
{
    std::stack<int> yellow;
    std::stack<int> purple;
    std::stack<int> pink;
    std::stack<int> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        yellow.push(i + 1);
        purple.push(i + 1);
        pink.push(i + 1);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Yellow - ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= size(yellow); i++) {
        temp.push(yellow.top());
        yellow.pop();
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= size(temp); i++) {
        printf_s("%d", temp.top());
        yellow.push(temp.top());
        temp.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213384/discussion-on-question-by-sion-there-isnt-any-error-in-my-code-but-it-doesnt-r).

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loops don't make sense to me. You're increasing `i` and decreasing the size of the `std::stack` every time through the loop. The desired loop termination condition is very unclear.

If you want to move elements from one stack to another you can use [`std::stack::empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/empty) with a `while` loop.

```
while (!yellow.empty()) {
    temp.push(yellow.top());
    yellow.pop();
}
while (!temp.empty()) {
    printf_s("%d", temp.top());
    yellow.push(temp.top());
    temp.pop();
}
```